# Remove points that are repeated consecutively more than n times

Tags: r

I have a large data set with X and Y points. I want to animate it, so I want to remove the points that are fixed locations.I would like to remove rows where the same X and Y is repeated more than n times.

So far I did this, is there a more elegant solution? Thanks!

```
uniques <- unique(data[c("Lat","Long")])
uniques$values = row.names(uniques)
uniques2 <- inner_join(data,uniques,by=c("Lat","Long"))
reps <- data.frame(unclass(rle(uniques2$values)))
delete <- as.character(reps$values[(reps$lengths)>10])
data2 <- uniques2[! uniques2$values %in% delete),]
```

Comment: Need data and clarification regarding "X" and "Y" (presumably Lat" and "long").

Comment: You should probably paste the values together to make one vector to analyze with rle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the first of the rows where `x` and `y` start repeating, you could try the following approach with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

# Example data
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(rep(1, 5), 2:6, rep(7, 5)),
  y = c(rep(9, 5), 2:6, rep(8, 5))
)

# Cut-off value
n <- 3

# Remove unwanted rows
new_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(same_as_prev = x == lag(x) & y == lag(y)) %>% 
  group_by(x, y, same_as_prev) %>% 
  mutate(consec_count = n()) %>% 
  filter(consec_count <= n & same_as_prev) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 3):

Tidyverse-way would be

```
data2 <- data %>%
  group_by(Long, Lat) %>%
  filter(n() <= 10) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: This solution assumes that locations are not revisited.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` I will try this one line solution:

```
library(data.table)
data < as.data.table(data)[, count:=.N, by=.(Lat,Long)][count<n][,count:=NULL]
```

Best!